# How to make .NET CLI know which connection to use for a context?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have EF Core 3.1 in my project. I have a context that in Startup I configure

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("YourConn").Value);
     options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```

I get that during app startup the connection string is clear, but when I want to do:

`dotnet ef database update` how will it know what connection to use?

Comment: You need to define the project or run this command in your startup project directory.

Comment: @tmsbrndz But how it will know which connection string to use for a given context?

Answer (score 0):

For EF Core 5.0 you can do the following:

> The dotnet ef database update command now accepts a new --connection parameter for specifying the connection string.

For older versions, you can specify the startup project in the command and it will use the same configuration:

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../YourProject.csproj
```